# Compiling zlib for windows mobile 6

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, zlib

I am trying to compile zlib for Windows Mobile in Visual Studio 2008.

However, that leads to an error. In the file zconf.h there is inclusion of the file sys/types.h.

While this file is in thw standard visual studio include directory, folder ce/include that comes with windows mobile sdk does not have sys subfolder in it, and it doesn't have types.h file here.

Consequently, zlb does not compile.

How should that be resolved?

Update: include itself is in the #if block. To be specific:

```
#ifdef STDC
#  ifndef Z_SOLO
#    include <sys/types.h>      /* for off_t */
#  endif
#endif
```

That brings to another question. Just what is the meaning of Z_SOLO macro? It is littered in #ifdef's and like in zlib, but searching for it doesn't give a clue about what is should be.
It is not defined, by the way.

Comment: Create your own sys/types.h header with the appropriate definitions and update your include path to find it

Comment: Sure, why not. I suggest you write that in answerssction, though, so that i could accept that if it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Z_SOLO` is used to compile and use zlib without the use of *any* external libraries.  It is for use in embedded environments.  There are no `gz*` functions and several other functions that depend on memory allocation are also taken out (`compress()`, `uncompress()`).  The base zlib initialization functions (e.g. `deflateInit()`) must be provided memory allocation functions.  This will avoid all of the problems you are having with Windows Mobile not having the standard C library headers and functions.

In order to use `Z_SOLO` you need to edit `zconf.h` to have a `#define Z_SOLO` near the beginning.  Then compile zlib and use it with the edited `zconf.h`.  (If you only compile with `Z_SOLO`, but do not edit `zconf.h`, then you'll get messed up with you try to use the compiled zlib with the header files.)

Comment: Worked just fine. I have put Z_SOLO definition in #ifdef(UNDER_CE) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go get the source, complete with Studio project files, that [I put out in CodePlex](http://zlibce.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Defining Z_SOLO and excluding all gz files from the project allows it to compile correctly.

gz (gzguts.h, gzread.c etcetera) files include fcntl.h, which is also not present in ce nclude folder, which is why they must go.